# 16.04 system booting to emergency mode. journalctl attached

Tags: boot, 16.04

here is a link to the output of journalctl -xb

https://gist.github.com/willrun4fun/714df68b5a38b56dceda4dc86cc92c30

system was running fine.  Restarted and got this.

EDIT:
Intel NUC 5i5ryh running 16.04.  16GB of Crucial matched ram, 256GB Crucial SSD.  System was up and running fine then crashed on reboot.  I have lxd and kvm systems loaded.  Just earlier I had installed this lxc management utility, could this cause it https://lxc-webpanel.github.io/

Comment: Please describe you problem in more detail.

Comment: Intel NUC 5i5ryh running 16.04.  32GB of Crucial matched ram, 256GB Crucial SSD.  System was up and running fine then crashed on reboot.  I have lxd and kvm systems loaded.  Just earlier I had installed this lxc management utility, could this cause ithttps://lxc-webpanel.github.io/

Comment: Please re-read my answer, with edits, below. It still sounds like a memory problem. You probably have 2 16GB memory sticks. My process is still the same. If I'm correct, please change the vote rating of my answer. Cheers, Al

Comment: I will try that, but the instal for that program messes with the cgroup configuration and that is what is failing to load in the crash log.

Comment: **Resolved**  The install script for that program had added a mount for cgroup to the fstab that prevented systemd from being able to mount it later.  Removed mount statement and I am back up and going :)

Comment: Did that also solve the problem with the memory? Does it recognize all 32G of RAM now, without all of the messages regarding "gran_size"? Cheers, Al

Comment: If you Google "*BAD*gran_size" it'll show you a GRUB fix for this memory problem. After applying the fix, you might be able to add back your cgroup mount. Cheers, Al

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved** The install script for that program had added a mount for cgroup to the fstab that prevented systemd from being able to mount it later. Removed mount statement and I am back up and going :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that you have a memory problem. I assume that you have a UEFI machine, and it doesn't show the memory test on the GRUB screen shown at boot time.

Since you have 16G RAM, I suspect that you have 4 sticks of 4G RAM in your memory slots, and are configured as interleaved memory.

First I'd try to reseat the existing memory sticks to see if that solves your problem. Power off the machine, unplug the AC power cord, then depress the power button, and you'll probably see the fans spin for a brief second. Now, touch a NEARBY grounded metal pipe to discharge any static electricity. To reseat the RAM, use the memory clips on either side of each RAM stick, and PARTIALLY eject the RAM, and then push it back in to reseat it. Do this for all of your RAM sticks. After that, plug in the AC power cord, and reboot your machine.

If that didn't fix the problem, try removing two sticks of RAM *(use the same AC power cord removal as above)*. Look for the RAM sockets to be white/black, and remove the pair from the same colored sockets. Try the machine again. If that didn't help, reinsert the removed RAM, and take out the other pair. Retest the machine.

Good luck,

Cheers, Al

edit: Well, if **you say that you have 32GB RAM, it appears to only see 16GB**, so I may have been correct... If you Google "**BADgran_size**" it'll show you a **GRUB fix for this memory problem**. After applying the fix, you might be able to add back your cgroup mount.

Comment: OR you could use memtest in the USB